# Install JDK7 on mac 10.6.2

Tags: java-7, osx-snow-leopard

I want to install JDK version 7 on my mac Snow leopard (32bits) 10.6.2
How can I do it ? Pleas give me some help ? is it possible or not ?

Comment: You can do it using [brew](http://brew.sh/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can install it following this tutorial.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/mac/mac-jdk.html

Answer (score 0):

Accordding to the tutorial, In order to install jdk version 7, the System Requirements is
**Any Intel-based Mac running Mac OS X 10.7.3 (Lion) or later.**

My mac version is **10.6.2 with 32 bits**